# javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException + org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm catching `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` which works great, but I'm getting the stacktrace of `StaleObjectStateException` in my server log. I've checked and the `getCause()` on `OptimisticLockException` returns `StaleObjectStateException`, but why is it printed out to server.log? It's really annoying, I'm writing a test, where two thread are modifying the same object, and one of the are throwing `OptimisticLockException` which is expected, but getting stacktrace of `StaleObjectStateException` is not what is wanted.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are both threads updating objects ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've encountered [#HHH-3442](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3442) (or one of it's duplicates). Update your Hibernate.

Comment: The bug is rejected. So the only solution seems to be to disable logging for `org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener`.